# Creating multiple intro screens in nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to create an intro screen for an app I'm building using [nativescript](/questions/tagged/nativescript) and [angular](/questions/tagged/angular). However, I didn't found anything about this type of view, so I don't know exactly what to use in this case.

This intro should be visible only on the first access, but this part I think it's pretty straight forward. I'll be using `applicationSettings` and checking if a given property (e.g. `firstAccess`) is `false`, indicating it's user's first access.

But how can I create the actual intro? These images show exactly what I want to build:

[image][image]

I almost did it using `TabView`, but it's definitely not the way to go. I can't match the styles to the one like in the images, etc.

What component should I use to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

There is no component to create something like that in {N} but there is available plugin you can use. Please see https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-slides

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.